# How to use an exported Cycles image as a projected image in Unity?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, unity, baking

I have this simple test scene with every object having a different color. It's hard to explain, but what I want to do is:

1. Render this 3D scene (in Cycles) from the camera view, then save the image (pic 1).
2. Projecting the image onto the 3D scene (pic 2).
3. Bring the scene with the projected image into a game engine (Unity).

My game does'nt require the camera to be moved around, so you are basically just looking at the scene from one view, so basically 2D. This is why I thought I could cheat and only show the textures that are facing the camera.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Please keep in mind that I want to capture the look of the rendered image in Cycles, so that I can make great looking scenes and keep that when bringing it into Unity.

(It's fine, too, if you know any other way to make an entire scene in Blender Cycles and bringing it into Inity, but maintaining that look.)

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Comment: I would be tempted to just recreate each material and the lighting in Unity, as it has okay diffuse shaders by default. That way you just need to worry about getting the models into Unity, and don't need to worry about textures and UV mapping (assuming your scene won't need textures in the future).

Answer (score 1):

1. Render your view to an image `Rendered.png`
2. Go to **UV Editing**
3. Set the right pane (3D View) to camera view (<kbd>Num .</kbd>)
4. Select `Rendered.png` on the image viewer on the left
5. Choose one of your objects
6. Enter `Edit Mode` (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
7. Select All (<kbd>A</kbd>)
8. Press <kbd>U</kbd> and choose `Project From View`
9. Repeat steps 4-7 for all other visible objects
10. Go back to `Default` workspace
11. Open a node editor
12. Set up the nodes as shown
    [image: Projected node setup]

I don't know if *Window* Projection actually exports to **Unity** but I suppose there is an equivalent setting there. Actually the small cube does not need such a Texture Coordinate, and frankly I don't understand why the outer shell needs it, I was expecting it to work out of the box.

Comment: The other way would be to just bake all textures in cycles and use them in unity